# действие при вылете приложения

Tags: c#

Как выполнить код (к примеру запустить CrashReporter.exe) в случае вылета приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если под словом "вылет" вы подразумеваете необработанное исключение, то можно подписаться на событие [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

...

void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) 
{
    // Сделать что-нибудь полезное перед выходом
}
```

Это событие будет сгенерировано, если в системе произошло исключение но не нашлось ни одного обработчика для него. Подписавшись, у вас будет возможность выполнить код перед закрытием приложения.

Comment: а если исключение не в основном потоке то сработает ли, и если да, то в каком потоке выполнится этот обработчик?